# GCM / FCM: "Received ANDROID API key. Only SERVER API keys are accepted."

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to authenticate with google's FCM (formerly GCM) - and getting the following error message:

`Received ANDROID API key. Only SERVER API keys are accepted.`

I *am* providing FCM with an API key - which I got when I downloaded my service's "google_services.json".

perhaps its the wrong api key?

Answer (score 1):

and so it took a little while, but I found the answer: I was using the wrong key. the "server key" is shown in the UI (and not in the json file you download - which (I guess) is just for clients): settings->cloud messaging. its confusing, so I got confused.

(perhaps the folks in Google could rename the api key in the file to something like "client_api_key"?)